# � gets appended after Enter key press tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce

�  gets appended after Enter key press in tinymce editor on viewing the saved content 
Please provide the solution, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. As the data was stored in BLOB format in the database.
Used

```
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE",$variable_where_special_char_appears);
```

This Removed the speacial character inside  the variable.